# How to check if a string has the same characters

Tags: java

For example:

```
Input=zzzz Output=true
Input=zaqz Output=false
```

If possible, could it run without a if else statement?

Comment: Any reason why without `if/else`?

Comment: @HarshalParekh Uncle Bob's clean code principles say that if you can avoid if/else, you should definitely do it.

Comment: @UladzislauKaminski, my question was for the OP. Also, the principle is not referenced in the question. The OP could be a beginner and might even be misguided.

Comment: @HarshalParekh definitely agree with you. Just try to guess what halium means

Comment: Reopening as the duplicate target for which it was closed is specific to Regex. Using Regex can be one of many solutions.

Answer (score 4):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("zzzz".chars().distinct().count() == 1);
        System.out.println("zaqz".chars().distinct().count() == 1);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
false
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple iteration would suffice.

```
String s = /* input string */;
char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
boolean samesies = chars.length > 0; //initial value
//see: ternary statements
char init = samesies ? chars[0] : 0; //get the first element, or the null character for an empty string
for (int i = 1; samesies && i < chars.length; i++) {
    if (chars[i] != init) {
        samesies = false;
        break; //optional, but can replace the "samesies &&" in your for statement
    }
}
//"samesies" has the appropriate value now
```

And in stream form:

```
String s = /* input string */;
boolean samesies = !s.isEmpty()
            && s.chars().allMatch(((Character) s.charAt(0))::equals);
```

The best thing you can do is to show us what you've tried, as critiques to your own code help you to see the problems defined in a way you would read it.

Comment: This seems over engineered. You can simply use a regex e.g. `string.matches("(.)\\1+") `

Comment: The point of the answer is specifically to answer it using only basics of the language (loops/arrays), not code golfing for the fewest lines. I'm not sure how new OP is to the language but I imagine it's beyond using regex lookarounds. If you want brevity, see Avinash's answer for a perfectly acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;

public class Checker {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s = read.readLine();
        boolean res = s.chars().distinct().count() == 1;
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```